# Update products with unique identifier different from sku

Tags: magento, csv, insert-update, magmi

I would like to update magento products with Magmi. The import csv file (with products to be updated) contains a column with unique id values but they are different from the sku values in database. Sku identifiers aren't available in this import csv file. The unique values in the import csv are a product attribute. So magmi should look up the sku value corresponding with each unique identifier in the import csv and then update the product with the sku that has been found. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes , using the [SKU Finder](http://www.blinkdata.com/magmi-sku-finder/) plugin.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best way. Unfortunately i get errors using sku finder : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ...

Comment: The SKU finder has been fixed in latest Git, there was indeed an error

Answer (score 0):

You can update the product quantities by selecting the ProductId (not the sku) in your database query. You should probably include an index on the ProductID, so you don't get a performance hit.

Your situation is normal -- you have a user known external "identifier" but keep your information by an internal prcess identifier. The options are to include:

1. Create a "productid" table, use this as an foreign key in your "sku
   based" table (and index)
2. Create a "productid" table with a mapping to your SKU table and use "join" when updating

You could experiment with both options, but your case appears simple enough to use option 1.